# Use Rundll32.exe to execute function exported by DLL

Tags: c, winapi, dll, rundll32

I have a DLL which exports a function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) 
void __stdcall MyEntryPoint(char* params)
{
    MessageBoxA("MyEntryPoint",params,0,0);
}
```

How can I use rundll32.exe to load my DLL and call `MyEntryPoint()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to define a function with a very specific signature in order for it to be callable by rundll32.  Have a look at [this blog entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043) for information, which includes details on how and why you may get crashes.

Also, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207411/218597) to a similar question, where the signature of the function is detailed.

Essentially for your function to be callable safely it would need to be defined as something like:

```
void CALLBACK MyEntryPoint(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR pszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
```

or

```
void CALLBACK MyEntryPointW(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPWSTR pszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
```

Anything else will corrupt the stack and may (or may not) cause a crash.  I think that in later versions of Windows, rundll will first look for the `MyEntryPointW` function, and if found call that - the difference is in the Unicode `pszCmdLine` parameter.

For more information on how to use `rundll32`, have a look at [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787), which details what to expect for each of the parameters, etc.

Comment: FYI `C:\> rundll32 user32.dll, MessageBeep -MB_ICONEXCLAMATION` will play a sound.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx returned a 403 for me just then

Comment: @micsthepick - I have updated the answer with a working link.  Possibly even to the correct article :)