# Documentation for writting your own dll for Rundll32.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, dll, rundll32

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Rundll32 to execute DLL Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207365/how-to-use-rundll32-to-execute-dll-function)

Where can I find documentation (tutorials, books, etc.) to write my own dll's that can be run with rundll32.exe?

Comment: There's not even a simple hello world there!!!

Comment: Sure there is! It gives you the signature of the only function that is relevant. You can add the `std::cout << "Hello World!";` part yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the most basic Hello World sample I could come up with that will work with `rundll.exe`. Please follow along these steps:

Start a fresh WIN32 DLL project in Visual Studio (I used VS2010)

In dlllmain.cpp add:

```
// this shoud ideally go into the .h file I believe
__declspec( dllexport ) void CALLBACK EntryPoint(
       HWND hwnd, 
      HINSTANCE hinst, 
      LPSTR lpszCmdLine, 
      int nCmdShow);

// our hello world function
void CALLBACK EntryPoint(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL,
        L"Hello World from Run32dll",
        L"Hello World",
        MB_ICONWARNING | MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2
    );

    switch (msgboxID)
    {
    case IDCANCEL:
        // TODO: add code
        break;
    case IDTRYAGAIN:
        // TODO: add code
        break;
    case IDCONTINUE:
        // TODO: add code
        break;
    }

}
```

Add a `module.def` file to your project and edit the following snippet in it:

```
LIBRARY YourDll
EXPORTS
    EntryPoint
```

Compile and then test from the commandline with

```
rundll32 YourDll.dll,EntryPoint
```

You should be greeted with a MessageBox with three buttons

I used the following url's to overcome C++ issues and *EntryPoint not found* in the early stages of my effort:

- [Rundll from user mricicle](http://everything2.com/title/rundll32)
- [How messagebox works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)
- [Exporting functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/a90k134d%28v=vs.100%29)
- [Exporting with .def file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh)
- [String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)