# Rundll32.exe doesn't function as expected, when attempting to call function in custom DLL

Tags: c++, security, mingw32, rundll32

I am learning how to write C++ in order to better understand how DLL work and how functions are called from within DLL. I am attempting to run **calc.exe** from within my DLL using **rundll32.exe**.  In my code (below), when executing **rundll32.exe** with my compiled DLL as a argument, I expect `spwncalc()` to get called from `DLLMain()` (regardless of what export function/ordinal I pass through **rundll32.exe**) and **calc.exe** to start.  I have also tried to call the `spwncalc()` function through the execution of **rundll32.exe**, but I can't get **calc.exe** to execute.

```
#include <windows.h>

void spwncalc()
{
        WinExec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe", 1);
}
BOOL WINAPI DllMain (HANDLE hDll, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved){
        switch(dwReason){
                case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
                        spwncalc();
                        break;
                case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
                        break;
                case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
                        break;
                case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
                        break;
        }
        return TRUE;
}
```

How could I change my code so that when I run `rundll32.exe calc_spwn.dll,spwncalc`, it executes my function?  Also, is there a way to get get it to load when the the dll is loaded through **rundll32.exe**?

Comment: You should never make Windows API calls from DllMain. See [this OldNewThing post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873) as a starting point.

Comment: Step 1 is to remove the function call from the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` handler. Step 2 is to note [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rundll32) that _"Rundll32 can only call functions from a DLL explicitly written to be called by Rundll32"_. Step 3 is to read [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11913860/1553090)... or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207411/1553090)... or see [this archived article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150109234931/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787)

Comment: So what should the code look like?

Comment: I'm not sure if you read my second comment. In Step 3 there are links to examples of what the code should look like.

Comment: @paddy Thank you for the response.  I'm not looking for other examples, but rather, changes to my code that will make it function in the way it is intended. I really appreciate the insight you have provided.  Thanks to you, I understand not to perform Win. API calls from DLLMain and have learned about loader lock.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: The examples show you how your program should be structured, including the entry point. You can look at it and adapt your program to be structured exactly the same.