# Host process for a C++ DLL

Tags: c++, dll, code-injection

I have a C++ DLL I've written that sometimes requires another instance of itself to carry out some actions. It would be nice if I didn't have to split it into 2 different parts, especially because I don't want any type of confusion that one of them is supposed to be "runnable".

I've been looking at a few system-ey processes on Windows I could start and inject into. svchost and dllhost have both caught my eye; but they weren't what I thought they were. Surely windows has some kind of generic DLL host I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like rundll32 is designed just for this purpose, and is exactly what I was looking for.

Command Line documentation:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787

Reference on usage (SO):
[How to use Rundll32 to execute DLL Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207365/how-to-use-rundll32-to-execute-dll-function)

Comment: But you must be aware of some reasons to avoid it...   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/04/10382242.aspx