# Need a solution to open a custom file, print it, close it, and move onto the next file

Tags: windows

Forgive me if this is the wrong place to look for help, but I have a problem in need of a solution:

We have a large collection of files with unique names that only open up in a specific editor. Embroidery files specifically (.dst or .pof). What I would like to do is print a matching library of these files as .pdfs. So, what I am after is a script or program that will open the file in the editor, print it, close it, and then move onto the next file in the folder till all are output.

Does something like this exist? Is there a custom script I could execute that would accomplish this?

Comment: It's not really the right place to ask, since you aren't asking about programming. I've voted to close as such. That said, you could use part of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200028/vbscript-list-all-pdf-files-in-folder-and-subfolders) to loop through all of the files you want, and combine it with the solution from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35359673/5240004), changing the first to use your file extensions, and the second to execute the 'print' verb.

Comment: You may need to search out a solution for picking the output filename for your particular printer, but that depends on which PDF printer you have. You may be able to find a solution over at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) but you'd have to refer to their FAQ to see what's on-topic for their site.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the assistance and suggestions.